# Set variable via config file in mysql 5.6 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to set variable in /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
```

But after restarting mysql server via command "/etc/init.d/mysql restart"
variable isn't changed (the value is still 1).

Any advises?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure which file MYSQL is reading do

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

the first line of the output will tell you where MYSQL will look for its `.cnf` or `.ini` file

Comment: Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Comment: even if I set property to ~/.my.cnf it is not changed after server restart

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to know the conf file mysql is using..

```
mysql --help | grep Default -A 1
```